# nginx not serving static files on a public server

Tags: django, nginx

I am trying to deploy a django project using nginx and gunicorn. I followed [this](http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/08/minimal-nginx-and-gunicorn-configuration-for-djang/) tutorial.

 Gunicorn is able to run my project but nginx is not serving static files.

My nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 69.12.74.39;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;
    }

    location /static/ {
      autoindex on;
      alias /home/ekodev/accounts/arham/ekomerz/static/;
    }
}
```

I checked the location of my static folder and its right. The gunicorn command i am using is:

```
gunicorn ekomerz.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:8001
```

EDIT: On my local machine it works fine.

```
server {
    listen localhost:8000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/manish/Desktop/ekomerz/ekomerz/static/;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Can you show your Django static settings? And have you run `manage.py collectstatic` on the server?

Answer (score -1):

You have Apache running on your Port 80 and nginx can't bind to Port 80.
View your log files.

You can stop apache with: `sudo service apache2 stop`

And start nginx with: `sudo service nginx start`

Comment: I dont have apache installed

Comment: There is no evidence that Apache is the problem here.

Comment: It ist installed by default or installed by an other package.
On your Server_name IP opens a default apache page.

Alternatively the Servername is wrong, so nginx won't match the locations.

Edit: Now there opens nginx.

Comment: Now the static Folder shows the right files.
But gunicorn ist stopped, so you get an 502 on every Site, expect /static/

Comment: Ok i tried that but still it is not working.. I tried it on my local and it worked fine.. I am updating my local settings

Comment: If I access the Site, it works fine. 
Only the Background ist loading very slow.

Comment: And you should change: proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001; to proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
And --bind=0.0.0.0:8001 to --bind=127.0.0.1:8001
so no other can access it.